# Error Out Of Memory in flutter and Android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, out-of-memory

today when i try to run my flutter project on android studio, unfortunately i have got this error:

```
c:\b\s\w\ir\cache\builder\src\third_party\dart\runtime\vm\zone.cc: 90: error: Out of memory.
version=2.7.0 (Mon Dec 2 20:10:59 2019 +0100) on "windows_x64"
thread=1736, isolate=main(00000239E9F1B690)
  pc 0x00007ff7ad514adb fp 0x0000003f991fc630 Unknown symbol
-- End of DumpStackTrace
```

how can i solve it?

Comment: I'm getting the very same issue when running "pub get" on cmd-line (Amazon Linux). The project is pure dart; no flutter.

Comment: You can try run flutter clean.

Comment: I have 16 gigs of RAM but still experienced this issue. Fyi, I run Android Studio with Emulator.

Answer (score 14):

I just restarted my laptop.It worked

Answer (score 10):

Restarting Android Studio is what worked for me
Go to

> File-> Invalidate Cache/ Restart -> Just Restart

Answer (score 4):

Try to do the following steps:

1. write this command in your terminal : `$ flutter clean`
2. in file tab bar click on **Invalidate caches**
3. restart

and it will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Got easiest solution is just delete the build folder of your **Flutter** project and Run again.

[image]

Taken risk but worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. Try the below solution:

1. Close Android Studio
2. Restart your Computer
3. Open C\Users\Your_Name\
4. Delete the file ".gradle"
5. Open Android Studio again and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`
3. `invalidate caches/restart`

Answer (score 0):

tyr running below commands in your project

```
cd android
flutter gradlew clean or ./gradlew clean
cd ..
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score -1):

In my:
\dart\runtime\vm\zone.cc: 90: error: Out of memory.

I'm change in yanl: 
from:
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl:

to:
 intl:
  flutter_localizations:

and reask:
pub get

Answer (score -1):

List item
2.cd android
3.flutter gradlew clean or ./gradlew clean
4.flutter clean
5.flutter pub get
6.in file tab bar click on Invalidate caches
7.restart

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

- There is no requirement to restart or clean the project.
- Just add the below line to your AndroidManifest.xml file & run the project.

> **android:largeHeap="true"**