# out of memory..end of dum stacktrace in flutter

Tags: flutter

i get this error while running my app in andriod studio using flutter i restarted my computer it worked fine... but when i hot reload or run the app multiple times i get this error again and i have to restart my computer again and again please tell a solution for this

Out of memory. version=2.14.0 (stable) (Mon Sep 6 13:47:59 2021 +0200) on "windows_x64" pid=8912, thread=7472, isolate_group=main(00000207B575E0E0), isolate=(nil)(0000000000000000) isolate_instructions=207b8af0000, vm_instructions=7ff700e24e50 pc 0x00007ff70102aa42 fp 0x0000009fed8fe8c0 Dart_IsPrecompiledRuntime+0x21a352 -- End of DumpStackTrace FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005 * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'. > Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insigh ts. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 9s Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... 11.0s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Android Studio is what worked for me Go to

```
File-> Invalidate Cache/ Restart -> Just Restart
```

in details [Error Out Of Memory in flutter and Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60019159/error-out-of-memory-in-flutter-and-android-studio)